# How to display only icons in floating menu for Textview's custom selection ActionMode (from API 28+)

Tags: java, android

I have implemented a custom selection actionmode in Textview which it's showed in floating mode.

I would like to show only icons for each MenuItem. Works perfectly in API 23-27 but not from 28, in which I'm forced to return to ActionMode.PRIMARY mode in order to see them.

The problem is little similar than this other question
[How to display menu item Icons on Android 9 in Floating Action Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004998/how-to-display-menu-item-icons-on-android-9-in-floating-action-mode)

Does anyone have the key?

**This is the menu:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/highlight_yellow"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_yellow_marker"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/highlight_blue"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_blue_marker"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/highlight_pink"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pink_marker"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/highlight_green"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_green_marker"
        android:title=""/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/highlight_underlined"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_underline_marker"
        android:title=""/>

</menu>
```

**This is the Callback:**

```
private class SelectionModeCallBack implements ActionMode.Callback {

        List<MenuItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            items.clear();
            menu.clear();
            clicked = null;
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bookmark_menu, menu);
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
                MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
                items.add(item);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            List<Integer> idsToRemove = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
                MenuItem item = menu.getItem(i);
                if (!items.contains(item)) {
                    idsToRemove.add(item.getItemId());
                } else {
                    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                }
            }
            for (Integer itemId : idsToRemove) {
                menu.removeItem(itemId);
            }

            return true;
        }

        MenuItem clicked = null;

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            clicked = item;
            final int start = readingTextView.getSelectionStart();
            final int end = readingTextView.getSelectionEnd();
            newHighlight(start, end, Highlight.Style.getStyleFromMenuId(item.getItemId()));
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            if (onCancelMenuSelectionListener != null && clicked == null) {
                onCancelMenuSelectionListener.onCancelMenuSelection();
            }

        }

    };
```

**This is the asignation**

```
myTextView.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new SelectionModeCallBack());
```

**The result**

The floating menu appears but each menuItem is represented by its title (empty text), so we only get the space for those items. In these cases, with API23-27, the icons were showed; but not from 28+.